# White admin login screen on magento 2

Tags: magento2

All of a sudden I'm getting a white screen when trying to login into my site. I had a look at my apache error log and found the following. Is anybody able to give me a clue on what the problem is and how to solve it?

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Can't
>   create directory
>   /var/www/html/magento/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/.'
>   in
>   /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:103\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35):
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\Framewo...')\n#1
>   [internal function]:
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\Framewo...')\n#2
>   [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\Framewo...')\n#3
>   /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19):
>   ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\Framewo...')\n#4
>   /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44):
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\Framewo...')\n#5
>   /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(71):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ in
>   /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php on
>   line 103

Comment: Check owner/permission of /var/www/html/magento/var.

Comment: drwxrwx--- 12 magento www-data

Comment: Just for testing make it 777. Also rename the "generation" folder (eg `mv generation generation.bk`

Comment: Thanks for your help and pointing me in the right direction..

Answer (score 0):

Re owning the `/var/www/html/magento/var` directory fixed this problem.

See here:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html